# add text file to zip before download (js)

Tags: javascript, zip

I need to add a new text file into an existing zip file (.tgz) before it is downloaded.
How should I approach this?

The text file is created on the fly.

What is missing is the steps to unzip the existing file, and then zip it again with the new text file.

Please advise,
Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to do this in a browser, right?

Comment: That is correct. I want to do this in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I *strongly* suggest you look at a server-side solution, because what I have found indicates that what you want isn't simple.  If you are decided that this has to be a client-side solution, then here are some resources that would be helpful to you:

### NPM

[NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/) is the package manager for [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).  NPM has a *huge* registry of javascript modules with various functionality.  Most of the modules on NPM are meant to run on Node.js (server-side) instead of a browser (client-side).  There are several modules that can work in both, however.

### Browserify

[Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is a NPM module that let's you code browser-apps in the same style as Node.js apps.  It handles all of the dependencies and is pure magic.

### `.tgz` vs `.zip`

I'm not sure how much you (or anyone in the future) knows about `.tgz` / `.tar.gz` (same thing) files, so I'll explain them a little bit.  If you already know this, skip this section.

A normal `.zip` file actually does 2 different things:

1. Combines the file(s) you want into one file
2. Takes the converted file and compresses it, thus outputting the `.zip` file

With `.tar.gz` and `.tgz`, however, these steps handled separately.  The extension `.tgz` is actually shorthand for `.tar.gz`.  The extension indicates that some file(s) have been combined into a `.tar`, and then compressed into a `.gz`.

If you want to inject a text file into a `.tgz`, these are the steps you need to take:

1. Decompress the `.tgz` into a `.tar`
2. Unpack the `.tar` into memory
3. Inject your text file into the original `.tar`'s files
4. Repack the modified files into a `.tar`
5. Compress the `.tar` back into a `.tgz` or `.tar.gz`

---

Writing something from scratch to do this would likely be a monumental task, so I'll try to just set you on the right path.

If you look at Browserify's documentation, it has its own browser-version of the node module [zlib](https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserify-zlib).  Zlib handles `gunzip` compression.

For handling `tarballs`, there are a lot of different modules on NPM that could potentially help you (just search on NPM for "tar").  I have absolutely no idea which ones can be browserified or not, so that will take some trial and error.

Good luck

**Sidenote:**  Something else you could potentially do is, instead of trying to unpack the origianl `.tgz`, you could pack the original`.tgz` up with your text file into a `.tar`, thus completely bypassing the steps 1, 2, and 5.